# GEMMLowP at lower bit depths

Tags: python, tensorflow

Specifically in the context of Tensorflow's use of GEMMLOWP for quantized operations, I would like to run quantized operations at varying bit depths.

[This readme](https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/blob/master/doc/less-than-8-bit.md)  seems to have some useful information but I still don't quite understand how to use it or what the impact will be - when it says the final data type is still a uint8, but lower accuracy, does this just mean that for example 7 bit arithmetic will return values from 0 to 127 despite being stored in a uint8 variable? Not sure if I'm interpreting that right.

Tensorflow seems to make use of GemmLowP's [MultiThreadGemm function](https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/blob/010bb3e71a26ca1d0884a167081d092b43563996/meta/multi_thread_gemm.h) - this can be found in [/tensorflow/core/kernels/meta_support.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/982549ea3423df4270ff154e5c764beb43d472da/tensorflow/core/kernels/meta_support.cc).

The MultiThreadGemm function takes in one Params structure; I can't see how to integrate the [BitDepthParams](https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/blob/master/public/bit_depth.h) which as far as I can see sets the precision into the Params structure in order to adjust Tensorflow's use of MultiThreadGemm for arbitrary bit depths.

Any insight/suggestions would be useful!

Comment: That readme may be outdated. Yes, it says that less than 8bit values are just stored as full 8bit bytes (in uint8_t). As said in https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/blob/master/doc/less-than-8-bit.md#implementation less than 8 bit are actually handled at packaging/unpackaging stages (check pseudocode https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/blob/master/doc/design.md with pack/unpack "*Inputs and outputs are matrices of uint8 values, but internally we are accumulating int32 values, only converting them back to uint8 at the end*"). So actual GEMM computation is not in less than 8 bit precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when it says the final data type is still a uint8, but lower accuracy, does this just mean that for example 7 bit arithmetic will return values from 0 to 127 despite being stored in a uint8 variable?

Yes, it says that less than 8bit values are just stored as full 8bit bytes (in uint8_t; it will have too high cost to unpack array of real 4-bit or 6-bit values into something compatible with vector ALU/AVX/GPU operations). More it says that input was (for the "present" before feb 2017) still full range 8-bit ints:

https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/blob/master/doc/less-than-8-bit.md#how-does-bitdepthsettingparams-affect-inputoutput-uint8-matrix-data

> Input/output matrix data is all uint8's, ranging from 0 to 255, regardless of the BitDepth{Setting,Params}.

Internally gemmlowp did repack input data into uint8_t storage with narrower range at packing stage (internally to gemmlowp, just before doing actual gemm matrix multipy, check general pseudocode of gemm in [design.md - impact of low precision](https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/blob/master/doc/design.md#impact-of-low-precision-computation-on-gemmlowp-design), note `pack` and `unpack`):

https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/blob/master/doc/less-than-8-bit.md#packing-stage

> Here, we have to scale input matrix values from their original range of [0 ... 255] to the range specified by the BitDepthParams, which is [0 ... (2^N)-1] where N is the number of bits for the matrix at hand (Lhs or Rhs). For example, for a bit depth of 5 bits, we need to scale down to [0 ... 31].

https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/blob/master/doc/design.md#impact-of-low-precision-computation-on-gemmlowp-design

> Inputs and outputs are matrices of uint8 values, but internally we are accumulating int32 values, only converting them back to uint8 at the end.

There were huge changes in February 2017 in handling of less than 8 bit.

`BitDepthParams` probably were integrated into the library in past, but the commit from Feb 2017 adds "*This 'present' state just became the past (February 2017).*" to the `less-than-8-bit.md` documentation and also removes usage of `BitDepthParams` in real code. Probably now input whould be not in full 8-bit range. Didn't find the place of kernel selection...

https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/commit/4746387c02f2b9542fe5d4a6ac4bb4d81f88ef15#diff-69cce824f316d701d9c3c23afcb00694 "Remove the old requantizing less-than-8-bit stuff."

> Remove the old requantizing less-than-8-bit stuff. Map the
>   DefaultL7R5BitDepthParams setting to DefaultL8R8BitDepthParams so that
>   this change does not break any user relying on it, since the whole
>   point of requantization was to make this an implementation detail.
>
> Instead, from now on, using actual less-than-8-bit settings will only
>   have the effect of selecting a different GEMM kernel. In other words,
>   it is now the responsibility of the user to know the actual bit-depth
>   (i.e. range) of their 8bit values. In exchange for that
>   responsibility, users of lower-than-8-bit depths will enjoy the
>   increased performance of corresponding kernels without the overhead of
>   requantization.
>
> ```
> -        PackLhs<BitDepthParams>(&packed_lhs, lhs.block(r, 0, rs, depth));
> +        PackLhs(&packed_lhs, lhs.block(r, 0, rs, depth));
> -        UnpackResult<BitDepthParams>(&result, curr_result_block, packed_result,
> +        UnpackResult(&result, curr_result_block, packed_result,
> -    PackRhs<BitDepthParams>(&packed_rhs, rhs.block(0, c, depth, cs));
> +    PackRhs(&packed_rhs, rhs.block(0, c, depth, cs)); internal/pack.h:
> -std::uint8_t Requantize(
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much! That clears things up; was very much struggling to wrap my head around the docs.